# Android jTreeMap visual

Tags: android, treemap

I need something special.

http://prefuse.org/gallery/treemap/

i need this, for android, is there a way to do it? how?

Answer (score 0):

Port it from Swing to Android's UI framework, using the Android 2D drawing API (`Canvas`). The whole prefuse framework is large and would take quite some time to port.

An even better approach is to generate your treemap on a server, sending the resulting PNG file down to the Android app. Depending on how much data you are processing, building a treemap on an Android phone could take quite some time, longer than the user wants to sit there.

Also, bear in mind that a traditional treemap is really designed for larger screens than most Android devices have, and so usability may be a problem.